# "Quite" before an adjective

Tags: adjectives, adverb-placement

> "THC has *a* **quite** *precise* modus operandi that taps into a specific brain function"

In the above example ([link](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/modus_operandi)), **`quite`** is used before the adjective **`precise`**

But [this OLD link](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/quite) says,

> When *quite* is used with an adjective before a noun, it comes before *a* or *an*. You can say: *It’s quite a small house* or *Their house is quite small* but not - *It’s a quite small house.*

So I'm quite confused here whether to use **`quite`** before **`a`** or after it. Which one of the following example is correct?

> "THC has **a quite** precise modus operandi that taps into a specific brain function"

Or

> "THC has **quite a** precise modus operandi that taps into a specific brain function"

And also please explain the grammar rule behind it.

Thanks

Comment: "Quite" can modify nominals as well as noun phrases. The latter is far more common, but there's nothing ungrammatical about "It’s a [quite small house]", and "THC has a [quite precise modus]".

Answer (score 1):

The grammar point you in the right direction, *"**quite** should come before **a**/**an** and even **the**"*:

> *"THC has **quite a** precise modus operandi that taps into a specific brain function"*

[BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv168.shtml) also states that the rule is **quite + a/an + (adjective) noun**:

> When quite is used to modify nouns or adjectives with nouns, it normally has the meaning of rather. Compare the following:
>
> - I know they left in a hurry. How did they leave the house? 
>     ~ Oh, it was in **quite a mess**.
> - How was the house contents auction? 
>     ~ Oh, it was **quite a success**. Nearly everything went.
> - Let's take a picnic with us. I think it's going to be **quite a nice day**.
> - Did you get to see Hamlet at the Barbican? 
>     ~ Yes, it was **quite an interesting production**.

The usage "**a quite + adjective**" is less common and appears more often in Academic writing. There's no other difference between the two even if some state there is.

Comment: I found that example with *"a quite precise"* in this site - https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/modus_operandi

Answer (score 1):

> THS has a quite precise modus operandi that laps into a specific brain function.

There's nothing wrong grammatically with this sentence.  You cn also say "......has quite a precise modus operandi......".

You normally use the format "quite a/an + adjective + noun".  However, in case of the adjective precise, the use of "a" before quite is more common according to Ngram viewers.

Comment: I find your answer useful. But, can you explain this example - "She was a quite unusual and extraordinary being"?. The word "unusual" can be "very unusual" sometimes, which means it's gradable.

Comment: Yes, but "precise" is gradable. "very/slightly/quite/extremely precise" and so on.